# Dynamic Linking Error - Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, runtime-error, dynamic-linking, dylib

I'm trying to link the Box2D C++ library to my Xcode 4.4 project through the *libBox.2.1.0.dylib* file. Here's what i did:

1. Went to the "Targets", selected my application, and added my *.dylib* file in the "Link Binary With Libraries" section
2. Created a new "Copy Files" build phase and set it to "Executables" (so the *.dylib* file is right next to the internal executable in the *.app* bundle)
3. Successfully compiled my project with no errors whatsoever
4. Ran project and got the following runtime-error:

   `dyld: Library not loaded: libBox2D.2.1.0.dylib`

   `Referenced from: /Users/****/Documents/Xcode Projects/ProjectName/DerivedData/ProjectName/Build/Products/Debug/ProjectName.app/Contents/MacOS/ProjectName`

   `Reason: image not found`

I followed all the steps from [this link here](http://www.vislab.net/people/john-stavrakakis/johns-blog/xcodehowtolinkdyliblibraryfiles), but I still get the runtime-error for some reason. I am I missing something important in my setup?